# My json response is coming in different format than I expected

Tags: ios, foundation, decodable

In browser my url gives results in perfect JSON format as follows

```
"articles": [
{
"source": {
"id": "the-times-of-india",
"name": "The Times of India"
},
"author": "Times Of India",
```

But Where as in Xcode output the response I am getting is as follows. How to convert this response into perfect json format

```
{
    articles =     (
                {
            author = "Times Of India";
            content = "Hyderabad: Senior Police officials arrive at the site of the encounter. All four accused in the rape 
            description = "India News: All four accused in the rape and murder of woman veterinarian in Telangana have been killed in an encounter with the police. Cops claimed they tried t";
            publishedAt = "2019-12-06T04:15:00Z";
            source =             {
                name = "The Times of India";
            };

        },
```

I am using the following code to decode the json data

```
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            guard let dataResponse = data, error == nil else {
                      print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Response Error")
                      return

            }
            do{
                //here dataResponse received from a network request
                let jsonResponse = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: dataResponse, options: [])
                print(jsonResponse) //Response result

             } catch let parsingError {
                print("Error", parsingError)
           }
        }

        task.resume()
```

Please help me with this issue.

Comment: Can you show me JSON url?

Comment: The response on your XCode has an `articles` key in it while the browser response does not. Are you sure that you are using the same `url` in both cases?

Comment: Yes. I am using the same url, I simply removed that part. Actually both has articles key. Instead of colon(:) I am getting  equals(=) sign. I just changed it again.

Comment: What is the issue? The first output is JSON (by the way it's not valid JSON), the second output is the result of `print(jsonResponse)` which is the `description` of a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

first you must create a Decodable struct and put it before viewController class:

```
 struct YourArrray: Decodable {
    let author: String?
    let content: String?
    let location: String?
    let description : String?
    let publishedAt : String?
    let name: String?
 }
```

declare your Url:

```
let jsonUrlString = "https://yourUrljson"
```

after that create your struct array var:

```
var myVar = [YourArrray]()
```

now you can procede to decode json:

```
fileprivate func fetchJsonObject() {
    guard let url = URL(string: jsonUrlString) else { return }

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, respons, err) in
        guard let data = data else { return }
        do {
            let jsonResponse = try JSONDecoder().decode([myVar].self, from: data)
            print(jsonResponse)
        } catch let jsonErr {
            print("Error serializing:", jsonErr)
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

Now you can simply call the function fetchJsonObject() and you're done
Hope this help :)

Comment: @Bhargav I recommended, Use optional value for the model class. If you are not received any value from array then parsing will fail.